# Distributing pairs of coloured socks to people

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Say you have $100$ socks, where $50$ are black, $30$ are white, $20$ are blue. You want to distribute them to $10$ different people such that none of them end up with an odd number of any colour, but there is no requirement that all $10$ people get socks. We are assuming the socks are identical other than colour and the people are all distinguishable. My solution is:

There are $25$ pairs of black socks, $15$ white, $10$ blue. There are

$\binom{10+10-1}{10}=\binom{19}{10}$ ways to distribute the blue socks,

$\binom{25+10-1}{25}=\binom{34}{25}$ ways to distribute the black socks, and

$\binom{15+10-1}{15}=\binom{24}{15}$ ways to distribute the white socks.

So there are $\binom{19}{10}\binom{34}{25}\binom{24}{15}$ total ways to distribute the $100$ socks such that nobody gets an odd number of any of the socks.

Would anybody be able to check my solution for this?

Comment: I assumed that when putting the socks into their pairs, that could clear up that nobody gets an odd number of socks, as you're just distributing pairs of coloured socks (treating one pair as one object). Is this not right?

Comment: Correct! I misread your text when I was editing. Sorry

Comment: Assuming the people are distinguishable and the socks are indistinguishable (apart from colour), this seems fine to me at first glance.

Comment: Yes, that's the assumption, I'll include that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into the Generating Function approach to this question.
The 25 black pairs of socks could be represented by;
$$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+...+x^{25})$$
and the ten boxes by raising this to the power of 10;
$$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+...+x^{25})^{10}$$
So, essentially, the answer could be obtained from expanding the brackets of;
$$(1+x+x^2+...+x^{25})^{10} \times(1+y+y^2+...+y^{15})^{10} \times(1+z+z^2+...+z^{10})^{10}$$
and looking at the coefficient of $x^{25}y^{15}z^{10}$ where $x,y,z$ represent black, white and blue pairs of socks respectively. This looks heavy going, although each part is a geometric progression;
$$\bigr(\frac{(1-x^{25})}{(1-x)}\bigr)^{10} \times \bigr(\frac{(1-y^{15})}{(1-y)}\bigr)^{10} \times\bigr(\frac{(1-z^{10})}{(1-z)}\bigr)^{10}$$
Keeping in mind that we're only after the coefficient of $x^{25}y^{15}z^{10}$ it might be possible to extract it$\dots$
Anyone want to take it on from here ?